# how to get only one row via DB::select method

Tags: php, laravel

I have a query

```
$result = DB::select("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id=$id");
```

I want to get one object, but it returns an array of objects.

I added `->first()` to my code as follows:

```
$result = DB::select("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id=$id")->first();
```

, and I got an error:

> Call to a member function first() on array

How to get one object via `\DB`?

Comment: FYI: You shouldn't concat variables like that in your query, this will leave you open to SQL injections

Answer (score 3):

Change it to use the query builder instead of the select statement

```
$result = DB::table('table_name')->where('id', $id)->first();
```

Comment: You know this advice exists elsewhere on Stack Overflow. When you answer duplicate questions, the Roomba can not do its very important job.

Answer (score 1):

DB::select method returns an array, and you are trying to call the first() method on an array which is not a valid operation. What that means is $result is an array. You can try this below which will filter based on one specific id in a safer way.

```
    $result = DB::select("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = ?", [$id]);

// Check if there is a result
if (!empty($result)) {
    // Get the first element of the array
    $row = $result[0];

    // Now you can access the columns of the row like $row->column_name
    $id = $row->id;
    $columnName = $row->column_name;

    // access other columns as needed
} else {
    // Handle the case where no result is found for the given ID
}
```

Comment: But why ask the database to return the full result set if you only intend to use 1 row?  This doesn't feel like best practice.